# JavaFX Scene Builder Accessing a Method in a different Class

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I've been looking for a workaround for this problem for a while now but haven't been able to find one.

I'm new to JavaFX, Scene Builder, FXML, CSS, the lot basically. I've had three months Java experience prior to this but that's it.

I have created a Project; JavaFX. I have created two Packages inside this Project; controller and view. Inside the controller Package there are two files; Login.java and AdministratorHomescreen.java. Inside the view Package there are four files; QuizApp.fxml, QuizApp.css, Login.fxml and AdministratorHomescreen.fxml.

I have been Googling and following different tutorials to learn how to do the various things, and so far I've been getting on alright. But now I've came to a stand still.

What I want to do, when my App starts and the user presses the Login button, is to forward them onto an Administrator Homescreen.

This is the code in Login.java:

```
public class Login extends Application {

private BorderPane quizApp;
private Stage windowLogin;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage windowLogin) {
    this.windowLogin = windowLogin;
    this.windowLogin.setTitle("QuizApp - Please Login or Register");

    windowLogin.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);

    applyQuizAppLayout();
    applyLoginLayout();
}

public void applyQuizAppLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Login.class.getClassLoader().getResource("view/QuizApp.fxml"));
        quizApp = (BorderPane) fxmlLoader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(quizApp);
        windowLogin.setScene(scene);
        windowLogin.show();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void applyLoginLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Login.class.getClassLoader().getResource("view/Login.fxml"));
        AnchorPane windowLogin = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
        quizApp.setCenter(windowLogin);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Stage getWindowLogin() {
    return windowLogin;
}

Button loginButton = new Button();

@FXML
private void handleLoginButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Login details correct.");
        // windowLogin.setScene(AdministratorHomescreen.start(windowAdministratorHomescreen));
    }
}
}
```

The line of code at the end which I have commented out is where I get the error. The error reads, "cannot be resolved to a variable". The button works to a degree apart from that, so when it is clicked a message to the console is displayed.

This is the code in AdministratorHomepage.java:

```
public class AdministratorHomescreen {

private BorderPane quizApp;
private Stage windowAdministratorHomescreen;

public void start(Stage windowAdministratorHomescreen) {
    this.windowAdministratorHomescreen = windowAdministratorHomescreen;
    this.windowAdministratorHomescreen.setTitle("QuizApp - Welcome Administrator");

    windowAdministratorHomescreen.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);

    applyQuizAppLayout();
    applyWindowAdministratorHomescreenLayout();
}

public void applyQuizAppLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Login.class.getClassLoader().getResource("view/QuizApp.fxml"));
        quizApp = (BorderPane) fxmlLoader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(quizApp);
        windowAdministratorHomescreen.setScene(scene);
        windowAdministratorHomescreen.show();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void applyWindowAdministratorHomescreenLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
                Login.class.getClassLoader().getResource("view/WindowAdministratorHomescreen.fxml"));
        AnchorPane windowAdministratorHomescreen = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load();
        quizApp.setCenter(windowAdministratorHomescreen);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Stage getWindowAdministratorHomescreen() {
    return windowAdministratorHomescreen;
}
}
```

So I know that the Compiler cannot find my variable, but any time I change the Method inside AdministratorHomescreen.java it throws up a load of new errors so I'm basically just going in circles now.

Is there anyway to work around this? I could well have went about this all wrong, but it's a learning curve at the end of the day.

Any help is much appreciated.

P.S. When the user clicks the button, I don't just want to open any random Scene, I want to open one which has QuizApp.fxml, QuizApp.css and AdministratorLogin.fxml already applied, hence the layout of my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the listener for your log on button you need to pass the relevant information to the next stage.

First set a listener for your log in button in your Logon class

```
loginbutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
     try{
       if("the login is successful"){
         String temp = "Your relevant user information, like username or however you keep track of your data";
         windowLogin.hide();
         //You'll then make a new stage to pass the info to the administrator page
         AdministratorHomeScreen nextStage = new AdministratorHomeScreen(windowLogin, temp);
        }
        else{
              System.out.println("incorrect login);
            }
        }
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
});
```

Then in your AdministratorHomeScreen class you'll do

```
public AdministratorHomeScreen(Stage stage, String takenOver){
windowLogIn = stage;
temp = takenOver;
start(new Stage());
}
```

I'm pretty sure that just about covers it.

Edit: Formatted the top bit of code to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So do I add these two new Methods into my existing code? Or for the Login Button do I need to replace my existing code with what you specified there? And will my FXML and CSS files still be applied?

Comment: Okay I tried all of that in countless different ways but none of it is working. Beginning to think I've just hit a dead end. Thanks anyway.